# JEE Main 2019:finding $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> let $f$ be a differentiable function such that $$f'(x)=7-\frac{3}{4} \frac{f(x)}{x}\tag 1$$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=?$

This came in JEE Main 2019.Although I got the answer $4$ which matches with the answer key,I( think my solution is not complete.

**Approach**:Assuming the limit exists we have by L-Hospitals rule $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to \infty}f'(x)=L \tag{say}$$ Then By taking $\lim_{x\to \infty}$ on both sides of equation $(1)$ we have $$L=7-\frac{3}{4}L \implies L=4$$

**Question**:Although this approach has quickly given the answer the problem is that I have assumed that the Limit exists which need not be the case.I am aware of the method of actually solving the differential equation and then calculating the limit as done [here](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/let-f-be-a-differentiable-function-such-that-fx/) but I was wondering if my method could be actually tweaked  to show that the limit exists or any other method without solving the differential equation.

Comment: Does this make you feel sad? That “bad maths” would solve this question (which I assume is multi-choice) in 1/10 the time of a rigorous solution?

Comment: @BenjaminWang yes its an MCQ ,There are many institutes in india which specifically train students to get the answer without even solving it>I  have a friend who solved a very tough question in JEE Main just by playing with the options.I sometimes do such tricks myself so i am happy and sad!

Comment: @Aatmaj there is nothing sad about whats happening ,time managment  MCQ tricks are all part of of that,*marks being more impportant than knowledge* Well then how do you think a student can be graded without any bias,I am happy with what is happening ,it couldnt have been better. Also I dont think tricks are the only feasible way to crack JEE,the questions are decent and it is not beyond once reach so much so that one can only rely on tricks,Its not a 'Putnam'

Comment: All the best for JEE Mains and I hope you get into Advanced!

Comment: If I were doing this question and was in the JEE Main mindset, I'd try to find an example of $f$ which works in this case, because the term $\frac{f(x)}x$ tempts me to think polynomial, since polynomial degrees reduce by $1$ upon differentiation. Comparing leading terms of the differentiated polynomial leads to $f(x) = 4x$ working out, and you're done! JEE Main math section  $\mathrm{= {tricks}^{tricks} + practice}$.

Comment: What you want can probably be proven using an integral inequality but such a proof will be cumbersome and certainly not useful for the purposes of MCQ exams like JEE.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon well thats nice,but the problem is that incase there is no nice function satisfying you would have wasted  1 precious minute

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I shall be happy to see the proof, as i mentioned i already got the answer using the trick willing to see the rigorous proof

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore That is true.

Comment: @Aatmaj I am out of the high-school exam-grind, but I'd love to see your 70 pages on "playing with the options". I have never heard of such a thing. Thank you.

Comment: Long back in 1998, Jee changed the pattern that year and you know what they asked "prove that all altitudes of a triangle are concurrent via coordinate geometry". Needless to say most of students were not prepared for theorem proofs. IMHO that was the easiest maths paper from JEE in many years because it consisted of proofs and conceptual problems rather than tricks. Knowledge helps and I sailed through that paper.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh so did you clear JEE ?

Comment: Well that's what "sail through" means. Anyway I have not kept track of jee questions since 2003. So not really sure what they ask now (except for some questions discussed on this site).

Comment: Coming back to your question you can easily solve the differential equation as the integrating factor is $ x^{3/4}$ and solution does not take too much time.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah i know that was just curious if it could be done without that

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply L'Hopital's rule, you must show that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, thus satisfying the criteria that $f(x)/x$ is an indeterminate form.  This is the main gap in the solution.

The question about the existence of the limit in general is more subtle, since even if L'Hopital's rule may be applied to an indeterminate form, the resulting limit may not be finite; e.g., $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^2}$$ has an indeterminate form of the same type but obviously does not have a finite limit.  That said, what your work does show is that if the limit is well-defined and finite, it must equal the value you obtained.

Comment: Ok, I know the fault in my solution ,my question was is there anyway to complete the solution without solving for f(x)

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore It is not that your solution is a "bad" one, it's simply not *rigorous*.  For the purpose of answering a multiple choice question, your approach is a perfectly acceptable exam strategy.  If, however, the answer had to be in the form of a proof, then you would not be likely to get full marks.  Rather than trying to make your approach rigorous, it is probably better (in terms of time and less creative effort) to employ the straightforward approach of solving the differential equation, thus eliminating any doubt about the existence of the limit.

Comment: Actually I already knew my mistake as i have mentioned in the question,,the purpose of posting this question was to get  any nice way to show that the limit exists without solving the differential equation Do you have any idea?

Comment: If you want to show that the limit  f(x)→∞ as x→∞, then it is actually quite easy, integrate the expression $f'(x)=7-\frac{3}{4} \frac{f(x)}{x}$